# Grails - How to Bootstrap xml Fixtures in SeleniumConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, selenium, fixture

I have xml data fixtures that I would like to use only when running my selenium tests. I would like to bootstrap a fixture to run from within SeleniumConfig.groovy, but I am not very familiar with bootstrapping or fixtures..

Can anyone please provide me some guidance? Thanks in advance.